# Json contains with exclusion or wildcard

Tags: json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

*Is there a way to either wildcard or exclude fields in a json_contains statement (postgres w/ sqlalchemy)?*

For example, lets say one of the rows of my database has a field called MyField which has a typical json value of ...

```json
MyField : {Store: "HomeDepot", Location: "New York"}
```

Now, I am doing a json contains on that with a larger json variable called `larger_json`...

```json
larger_json : {Store: "HomeDepot", Location: "New York", Customer: "Bob" ... }
```

In sqlalchemy, I could use a `MyTable.MyField.comparator.contained_by(larger_json)` and in this case, that would work fine.  But what if, for example, I later removed `Location` as a field in my variable... so I still have the value in my database, but it no longer exists in `larger_json`:

```json
MyField : {Store: "HomeDepot", Location: "New York"}
larger_json : {Store: "HomeDepot", Customer: "Bob" ... }
```

Assume that I know when this happens, i.e. I know that the database has Location but the larger_json does not. Is there a way for me to either wildcard Location, i.e. something like this...

```json
{Store: "HomeDepot", Location: "*", Customer: "Bob" ... }
```

or to exclude it from the json value?  Something like this?

```py
MyTable.MyField.exclude_fields().comparator.contained_by(larger_json)
```

Or is there another recommended approach for dealing with this?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you have the larger JSON in your database, and you want to search with a smaller JSON that is contained in it, or does the database contain the smaller JSON, and you want to search for everything that is contained in a certain JSON?

Comment: The database contains the smaller json (MyField) and I want to find it by doing a json.contains with the larger json.  The issue is that one of the fields in the smaller json, like Location in this example might get removed from the larger one.  in that case, the smaller one has a field the larger one does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's what you need, but you could remove `Location` as a key from the values you search:

```
... WHERE (tab.myfield - 'Location') <@ larger_json
```